# python social auth redirect to an error page conditionally

Tags: python-social-auth

Am using python social auth with django to create authentication and registration via social media. I've defined the

> LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/account/auth-failed/'

it works well when there is a problem, it would redirect there correctly. Yet, I want to conditionally specify the LOGIN_ERROR_PAGE at run time because I have a scneario where its invoked via JSON or simple HTML.

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really simple to implement, but you can override the default strategy and in your custom version override the `get_setting()` method, like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

from social.strategies.django_strategy import DjangoStrategy


class CustomDjangoStrategy(DjangoStrategy):
    def get_setting(self, name):
        if name == 'LOGIN_ERROR_URL' and self.request.is_ajax():
            return '/auth/error/ajax'
        else:
            return getattr(settings, name)
```

Put that into a module and define `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = app.module.CustomDjangoStrategy` in your settings.